# preimage of a semi-circle under $p(z)=z^2$

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $e^{i\theta} \in S^1$, consider $f:\Bbb R \to S^1$ given by $f(t)=e^{it}$. Let $U$ be the image of the set $(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2},\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})$ under $f$ it's the open semicircle centered at $e^{i\theta}$. Finally let $p:S^1 \to S^1$ given by $p(z)=z^2$. I want to find $p^{-1}(U)$ and prove that it consist in two open sets (relative to the subspace topology of $S^1$ that are homeomorphic to $U$ by $p$. I don't know how to find the preimage.

$e^{it} \in p^{-1}(U) \Leftrightarrow e^{2it} \in U \Leftrightarrow 2t\in (\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi,\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$ for some $k\in \Bbb Z$

How can I continue?

Comment: And what if $p(z)=z^n$?

Comment: In that case, I think you would use your method with $k=0,\cdots, n-1$ to get n open sets.

Comment: @user84413: Your comment is what I'd have written in an answer. Do you want to post this as an answer, to get this question out of the unanswered queue?

Comment: @MvG Okay, if this seems an appropriate thing to do, I will.

Answer (score 1):

I think you now want to use that $t\in(\frac{\theta}{2}−\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi,\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi)$, where you only have to consider $k=0$ and $k=1$, since angles differing by $2\pi$ correspond to the same point in $S^1$.